# How to take only best score from array?

Tags: elasticsearch

I try use multi_match with type = best_fields for take score of best field in array, but I get sum scores of items in array. How to create request, which get only max score of array item and ignore other item scores?

Documents:

```
1: { "field": ["a b c", "b c"] }
2: { "field": ["e f g", "b c"] }
```

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "c",
      "fields": [
        "field"
      ],
      "type": "best_fields"
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
1: {"score": 0.39, "highlight": ["a b <em>c</em>", "b <em>c</em>"] }
2: {"score": 0.28, "highlight": ["b <em>c</em>"]}
```

Mapping:

```
 {
  "mappings": {
    "bft": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
          "field": {
              "type": "text"
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is actually possible for you to do what you're asking for here. The issue boils down to how arrays of strings vs a single value are treated by the scoring algorithm.

I did a bit of digging into this issue after seeing your question and the information I was able to find on the topic seems to imply that ["a b c", "b c"] is equivalent to ["a b c b c"] or "a b c b c" when it comes to scoring.

> When you get a document back from Elasticsearch, any arrays will be in
>   the same order as when you indexed the document. The _source field
>   that you get back contains exactly the same JSON document that you
>   indexed.
>
> However, arrays are indexed—made searchable—as multivalue fields,
>   which are unordered. At search time, you can’t refer to “the first
>   element” or “the last element.” Rather, think of an array as a bag of
>   values.
>   [Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/complex-core-fields.html)

To accomplish what you want, I believe you will need to break out your individual array values into their own document and provide another field that you could use as a filter to "group" your documents.